# In Rune Factory 4, how do I delete a save file?

Tags: rune-factory-4

My copy of Rune Factory 4 is pre-owned so has a save file on it which I want to delete. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm reading that you can just start a new game and overwrite the old saves, but have found nothing conclusive about erasing a save.

Comment: Thanks, I can't find anything either, seems it's not possible? I was going to pass it on to a friend and wanted it nice and clean but I guess it's no big deal, just seemed like there ought to be a way.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do, like in most games, is choose the old save file when you're saving a new one. It's the same for all RF games.